# Property of Reynolds Operator

Tags: group-actions, invariant-theory

Proposition 2.1.2 of Sturmfels' "Algorithms in Invariant Theory" has statement c): $\star$ is a $C[x]^\Gamma$ Module Homomorphism ie $(fI)^* = f^* I$ for $f\in C[x]$ and $I\in C[x]^\Gamma$. Where $\star$ is the Reynolds Operator $f^* = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} g(f)$.

I'm not familiar with Module Homomorphisms, so I gave it a shot at proving it myself, but I get

$$(fI)^* = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} g(fI)$$, but for the proof to work I would need $g(fI) = g(f)I$ which may not be the correct way to do it. In addition, I'm not sure how group actions are defined on ring multiplication. Since ring multiplication isn't a group generally, we cant seem to use any kind of group homomorphism properties. Can anyone give me some kind of general context that may help or another valid strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I had another go at it with different notation, which may or may not help.

With new notation, the Reynolds Operator is:

$$f^*(\bf{x}) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g.x)$$ where the group action "." acts directly on the dependence of f on $\bf{x}$. So this would make

$$(fI)(\bf{x}) = f(\bf{x})I(\bf{x})$$ so

$$(fI)^*(\bf{x}) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g.\bf{x})I(g.\bf{x})$$ but since $I\in C[\bf{x}]^G$, then $I(g.\bf{x}) = I(\bf{x})$. So it can be pulled out of the sum and thus the property is proved.

Comment: Answers are for answering the question asked, to to ask another question seeking feedback